# Typescript, Redux - Set type for DISPATCH

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

This has to be the most annoying thing I've ever dealt with.

How on earth do I set a type for a dispatch in react / redux / typescript? Code snippet below:

```
class MyComponent extends Component<StateFromProps> { // Do I need a <..., DispatchFromProps> here?
  ...
  const mapStateToProps = (state: StateFromProps) => {
    return {
      counter: state.counter
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      onAddCounter: (amount: number) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_COUNTER', value: amount })
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Several lines above, I defined interfaces for state and dispatch. This seems to work for state, but not for dispatch.

```
interface StateFromProps {
  counter: number
}

interface DispatchFromProps {
  onAddCounter: () => void  // I can't get this part right. I am getting errors about call signatures etc.
}
```

I would like to dispatch actions as follows:

```
this.props.onAddCounter(5)  // ERROR: Property 'onAddCounter' does not exist on type 'Readonly<StateFromProps>'...
```

Comment: Yes, your props passed to `class MyComponent extends Component<` should be the total of them. You can choose not to distinguish them to `StateFromProps` and `DispatchFromProps`, simply define both in `Props` and use it in your component would work

Comment: How do I define them in props? Do you mind posting a small example of this?

Comment: You can have a quick view of my demo repo [here](https://github.com/ibarapascal/netweather/blob/master/src/components/weather/WT.tsx), and [here](https://github.com/ibarapascal/access-catalog/blob/master/blog/summary-of-react-develop-practice/template-of-react-code.md/#View), and feel free to fork and try it yourself locally.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/

Comment: Yeah, the official way seems better if there are no further problems with that HOC

Comment: You can skip `(dispatch) => ` part and just return action creator, `connect` will do that for you

Comment: If you really need to use and type `dispatch` - you can import it from `redux`. Here's the source https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/types/store.ts#L79

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to almost work:

**Problem**: The `Component<T>` only seems to accept the first argument.

```
class MyComponent extends Component<StateFromProps, DispatchFromProps> {
  ...
}
```

I can access `State` when `StateFromProps` is the **first** type-parameter passed to `Component`.

When `DispatchFromProps` is the **second** argument, all the `Dispatch` code breaks.

If I change the order and put `DispatchFromProps` first, the `Dispatch` code works but all the `State` code will break.

How do I correctly use multiple types for `Component`?